# java api for layered graphs

Tags: java, api, graph, desktop-application

Which java based graph/chart api is most suitable for layered graphs in java based desktop applications? It is desired that the entire graph/chart is build up of several layers which can be shown or hidden later as per needs.Also, it would be nice if it provides in place editing ( temporarily, just for view ) of the graph/chart (especially line charts).

Answer (score 1):

You can use charts4j http://code.google.com/p/charts4j/ or very straight forward google chart api http://code.google.com/apis/chart/.